# VM Additions for ubuntu 8.10?

Tags: virtualization, virtual-pc, vpc

I know that VPC does not officially support Linux, but I was wondering if there are any ways to get things similar to the VM additions so that I can get:

- 1) A higher screen resoultion than 800x600
- 2) Faster graphics, no jerkey movements
- 3) Drag and Drop support

Number 3 really isn't that important but it would be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposedly you can download Linux VM additions for Virtual Server from http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserversystem/virtualserver/downloads.aspx, and transfer them to VMs to use in VirtualPC. This is “not supported” for Ubuntu or VirtualPC, but may work.

Personally I'm using VirtualBox for Linux guests; its additions work well under Intrepid. Still no drag-and-drop though unfortunately, that's certainly one feature I miss from VPC.

Comment: I'm thinking about switching to VirtualBox.

Answer (score 1):

It's not supported for Ubuntu, but there are Linux editions available here:

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=bf12642f-77dc-4d45-ae4e-e1b05e0a2674&displaylang=en&tm